# In rails how to require a coffeescript file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

In a rails application. I want to create a coffeescript function that can be shared by multiple coffeescripts.

for example

1. app/assets/javascripts/util.js.coffee

```
sample_function = (word) -> console.log word
```

2. app/assets/javascripts/sign_up/common.js.coffee

how to import and use the sample_function

I tried:

```
//= require '../util'
sample_function('hello world')
```

It says sample_function is undefined.

Comment: What Rails version? Are you using Webpacker?

Comment: the rails version is Rails 6.0.5.1 and I'm not using Webpacker